# Tikz: Creating narrow arrow heads / disproportionate scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, scaling, tikz-arrows, size

I want to use arrow heads that look like the `triangle 45`, but due to my technical background I would like to get the opening angle smaller (and overally smaller in relation to the line width).

My MWE here tries to get that by using decorations and a `scalebox` together with the `scale` option, but this approach skews and displaces the arrow head whenever the line is not in the origin axes (see red arrow).

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{%
arrows,
decorations,
decorations.markings,
decorations.text,
arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    arrow/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with
    {\scalebox{1}[0.5]{\arrow[scale=0.5]{triangle 45}}}},postaction={decorate},shorten >=1.5 pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[arrow] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[arrow,red] (0,-.5) -- (1,-.5);
\draw[arrow,red] (0,0) -- (-.7,-.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any simple solutions for my desired arrow heads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use draw commands in such a marking definition, the coordinate system is automatically aligned "along the path". So you can define it e.g. like in the following example. The `arrow` style has an optional argument that will scale the arrow tip.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    arrow/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with
    {\fill(-0.09*#1,-0.03*#1) -- (0,0) -- (-0.09*#1,0.03*#1) -- cycle;}}, postaction={decorate}},
    arrow/.default=1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \draw[arrow] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[arrow=1,red] (0,-.5) -- (1,-.5);
    \draw[arrow=10,red] (0,0) -- (-.7,-.7);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the angle, the easiest way would be to use the `scale width` key of the `arrows.meta` library:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->,>={Triangle[scale width=1.75]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[->,red,>={Triangle[scale width=0.15]} ] (0,-.5) -- (1,-.5);
    \draw[->,red,>={Triangle[scale width=1]} ] (0,0) -- (-.7,-.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]